# How to get common elements of values from map keys in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Following a series of Scala exercises to understand better high order functions. I have come across this problem. I have the following map:

```
val keyValues = Map("a" -> List(1, 3), "b" -> List(1), "c" -> List(1,3,4,5))
```

How could I get a list which contains the common elements of all the 3 lists of the key values, which would be:

`val common = List(1)`

and how could I get a list which would contain all elements of the key values together:

```
val all = List(1,3,4,5)
```

I am new to functional programming so I would really apreciate if someone could help me understand the logic behind it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, [**Sets**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html) is a great data structure for this kind of problems.

```
val keyValues = Map("a" -> List(1, 3), "b" -> List(1), "c" -> List(1,3,4,5))

val valuesAsSets = keyValues.valuesIterator.map(_.toSet).toList

val all = valuesAsSets.foldLeft(Set.empty[Int])(_ | _)
val all = valuesAsSets.foldLeft(Set.empty[Int]) { case (acc, set) => acc.union(set) }
// all: Set[Int] = Set(1, 3, 4, 5)

val common = all.filter(elem => valuesAsSets.forall(set => set.contains(elem)))
// common: Set[Int] = Set(1)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! could you explain to me what this line does: `(Set.empty[Int])(_ | _)` ?

Comment: @hispaniccoder `Set.emptyInt]` creates an empty set as the first argument of fold left, which is the initial value of the accumulator. `(_ | _)` is a shorthand to a function of two arguments where we call the `|` method _(alias for `union`)_ on the first argument of the function and we pass the second argument of the function as the argument of the `union` method. In resume, this is joining all the sets together.

Comment: @hispaniccoder Let me give you another advice, I would move all your questions to [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) it is a chat, so the answers will be more realtime and there will be more people. Also, they are friendlier with this kind of basic questions than SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! Do you have any other source from which I could find exercises in Scala to get more familiar? I went through the tour of Scala and now I am trying to find more exercises to practice.

Comment: @hispaniccoder technically sparking I shouldn't answer that here. So I would recommend you to ask that in the gitter channel I will be happy to answer you that question there or if I am not there at the moment you ask, you still will get a lot of good answers from many people.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `intersect`:

```
keyValues.values.reduce((l1, l2) => l1.intersect(l2))
```

And to get all:

```
keyValues.values.map(_.toSet).reduce((s1, s2) => s1 ++ s2).toList
```